# Parallax scroll bound animation, animating at different speeds

Tags: javascript, css, animation, parallax, scrollmagic

I want to create a scroll bound animation similar to the one shown in this video. I would like to do this in Javascript/CSS so I can implement it on any website.

I have been looking at using Scrollmagic.com but not sure this is possible with this Library.

Any ideas/ leads would be greatly appreciated.

Animation I am trying to achieve:  [1]: https://youtu.be/0ITA_pwfzDE?t=15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found this Javascript library that works very well, is easy to implement and lightweight.

https://dixonandmoe.com/rellax/